# differential forms on formal schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

iam learning formal schemes. Suppose $Y\subset X$ are schemes, and $\hat{X}$ is the completion of $X$ along closed subscheme $Y$.
I wondered if there is a notion of sheaf of differential forms on a formal scheme $\hat{X}$ and a 'de Rham' complex $\Omega^.$ whose cohomology has a relation with cohomology of $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: A good place to look might be Hartshorne's paper on de Rham cohomology of algebraic varieties.

http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1975__45_/PMIHES_1975__45__5_0/PMIHES_1975__45__5_0.pdf

In particular, Section 1.7 defines the object you talk about, and much of the paper is devoted to the study of its cohomology.

Comment: At least for varieties over a field of char 0 that is.